# Custom EditorTemplate for complex object takes main object members instead of member object's member

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mvc-editor-templates

I'm currently developing an interface for a system, and I'm facing a problem which seems strange to me.

I have a `Command` class, which looks like this:

```
public class Command
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Parameter` class is:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; } 
}
```

So I have created a view to edit the command and its arguments on the same page. I have an EditorTemplate for my class `Parameter` (in Views\Commander\EditorTemplates):

```
@model MyApplication.Models.Parameter

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my `Command` editor view (in Views\Commander):

```
@model MyApplication.Models.Command

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Parameters)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parameters)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

My problem is that my edit view takes `Command.Name` value and puts it in `Parameter.Name` field. It may be obvious for somebody, bud I really don't know what causes this. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

EDIT: Let's say my command is `RunExe -path C:\FooBar.exe`. When I open my Edit page for this command, instead of having `path` in my parameter name edit field, it shows `RunExe`.

And I still have `RunExe` in command name edit, and `C:\FooBar.exe` in parameter value edit.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem. I just had a typo when assigning value to my member which used the name of the command instead of th name of the parameter -_-'